# Authorize attribute authorizing any JWT token for the controller in asp.net core?

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to use **JWT** authentication in my ASP.NET CORE project.

**Step-1:** I have added the JWT service in **ConfigureServices** method of **Starup.cs** file.

```c#
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:SecretKey"])),
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateActor = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false
        };
    });
```

And added below code in the **Configure** method:

```c#
app.UseAuthentication();
```

**Step-2:** Sending the jwt token while login.

```c#
public class LoginRepository
{
    public LoginRepository()
    {
        //TODO: Dependency to MongoDB will be initialized here
    }

    public LoginStatus Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        LoginStatus loginStatus = new LoginStatus();
        string secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["Jwt:SecretKey"];
        int tokenExpirationHours = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["Jwt:TokenExpirationHours"]);
        //TODO: Need to add the userID in the payload. UserID will come from Database
        Dictionary<string, string> payload = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                { "UserName", username}
            };

        //TODO: Need to check the username and password in Database and then generate the token
        loginStatus.Token = JwtTokenHelper.GenerateJwtToken(secretKey, payload, tokenExpirationHours);

        return loginStatus;
    }
}
```

Here is the JwtTokenHelper:

```c#
public class JwtTokenHelper
{
    public static string GenerateJwtToken(string secretKey, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> payloadContents, int tokenExpirationHours)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));
        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

        var payloadClaims = payloadContents.Select(c => new Claim(c.Key, c.Value));

        var payload = new JwtPayload("", "", payloadClaims, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(tokenExpirationHours));

        var header = new JwtHeader(signingCredentials);
        var securityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);

        return jwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
    }
  }
```

**Here, I am getting the JWT token successfully.**

**Step-3:** Now, I tried to authorize a controller and it is working nice when I have given the token in the Authorization header from Postman.

```c#
namespace SampleAPI.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Test")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Testing")]
        public IActionResult Testing()
        {
            return Ok("Yes");
        }
    }
}
```

But, if I change something in the JWT token and again hit this endpoint, it is returning "**Yes**" means it is saying that the jwt token is valid. But I have changed some parts of that token before sending in the **Authorization** header.

What am I missing here? Can you please point me out what more steps should I follow?

Comment: What did you change in the token and is it still a valid token after that change? I mean, was a new signature calculated, so that the token is still valid?

Comment: I didn't parse the token though. I just reshuffled the token randomly and again tried to sent that token in Authorization header. And i could get the results without 401. Do i need to validate the token manually again? I am just kind of confused about the scope of this [Authorize]

Comment: Are you sure that you are sending a different one? I mean, if you use POSTMAN and you send a valid request, then make some changes on the Token manually and make the same call you still having an OK?

Comment: Is my implementation ok for asp.net core?